# Проблемы с CSS в IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Использую такие css свойства для кнопки "Заказать обратный звонок":

```
button#opener{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
        writing-mode: tb-rl !important;
        transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
        margin-left: -50px;
    }
    button#opener span{
      font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;
    }
```

В Хроме все ок, а вот с IE11 проблемы. Как решить проблему?
Посмотреть можно [тут](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень надо..

Comment: @eprivalov1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Уберите эту строчку из CSS:

```
writing-mode: tb-rl !important;
```

Она предназначена для версий IE 8 и ниже. Можно и без `!important` написать, но делать это нужно вот так, данный блок можно добавить в head:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <style type="text/css">
        button#opener {
           writing-mode:tb-rl;
        }
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Или можно создать отдельный файл только для IE 8 и ниже и в него добавлять нужные для этих браузеров стили:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <style type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" href="../path-to-file/style-ie.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @MasterAlex Спасибо за помощь